# Suppress pdflatex warning about missing eps file

Tags: pdftex, warnings, eps, epstopdf

I use .eps graphics in my latex documents converted at compile using the `epstopdf` package and it works great.

When I build the file, `epstopdf` creates the `<filename>-eps-converted-to.pdf` file and includes it in the resulting .pdf.

I would now like to now delete the .eps file and just use the converted`<filename>-eps-converted-to.pdf` file. This actually works, sort of - `epstopdf` doesn't complain (rightly or wrongly), it just returns

```
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
```

and the resulting .pdf contains the image as desired.

However, I get an annoying LaTeX warning

```
LaTeX Warning: File `test.eps' not found on input line 8.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{epsfig}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{test.eps}
\end{document}
```

Build this with any .eps file and it builds fine. Now delete or rename the .eps file and it still builds fine, but gives the annoying warning above.

**My question:** is there any way to just disable the warning for missing .eps files?

The reason for this is that I often auto-generate .eps files outside of the latex source directory and would like to just commit the latex source to git with the converted .pdf files (output locally by using the `[outdir=./]` option with `epstopdf`) but without the source .eps files - this way I or anyone else can build it stand-alone.

**Updated MWE** with .eps file outside the source path:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{suffix=}
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics{../test}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need `epsfig`: the recommended solution is to use `graphicx` instead. And you probably don't need `epstopdf` although the latter will not hurt anything.

Comment: don't use `epsfig` and use `\includegraphics{test}` rather than `\includegraphics{test.eps}` then all you need to do is check in the generated files as test.pdf and latex will use the eps if it is there and pdflatex will use the pdf it's probably simpler just to convert each of the eps externally  rather than getting latex to escape to teh shell to convert them

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you for the comment - that works well if the .eps file is in the source directory. Is there a solution if the file is outside the source dir and `[outdir=./]` is used with `epstopdf`? I have added a new MWE to demonstrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem that there is a way to prevent the warning showing up directly.

One work-around would be to use the [`silence`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/silence) package to filter out the warnings from the output.

However, `silence` doesn't detect these warnings as they're generated using

```
\@warning{File `#1' not found}%`
```

(line 166 of `graphics.sty`) and `silence` only picks up warnings generated using `\PackageWarning`, `\ClassWarning`, `\@latex@warning` and `\@font@warning` (lines 381-431 in v1.5b of `silence.sty`).

I have contacted the maintainer of `silence` about this but received no response, so the simplest solution is to place the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{silence}

\WarningFilter[latex_file_not_found]{latex}{File}

\makeatletter
\let\sl@warning\@warning
\def\@warning#1{%
  \def\sl@PackageName{latex}%
  \ifsl@NoLine
    \sl@NoLinefalse
  \else
    \sl@StoreMessage{#1}%
  \fi
  \sl@warning{#1}}

\def\@warning@no@line#1{%
  \sl@StoreMessage{#1}%
  \sl@NoLinetrue
  \@warning{#1\@gobble}}
\makeatother

\ActivateWarningFilters[latex_file_not_found]
```

This will ignore all `\@warning`s that start with `File`.

It is also possible to wrap all `\includegraphics` with `\ActivateWarningFilters[latex_file_not_found]` and `\DeactivateWarningFilters[latex_file_not_found]` to only apply this to graphics imports (I'm not sure where `File` warnings would otherwise show up).

Alternatively, this can also be automatically included in all `\includegraphics` calls with the following re-definition (credit to [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228411/44049)):

```
\makeatletter
  \let\oldGin@ii\Gin@ii
  \def\Gin@ii[#1]#2{%
  \ActivateWarningFilters[latex_file_not_found]%
  \oldGin@ii[{#1}]{#2}%
  \DeactivateWarningFilters[latex_file_not_found]}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

Package `epstopdf` can be reconfigured to remove the additional name suffix from the generated file name. The suffix was added to avoid accidental overwriting of `.pdf` source files. But if all images are `.eps` files, then these precaution measure is not necessary. The image file is then included without extension and the graphicx package will find the `.pdf` file or `.eps` file depending on the order given by `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions` (see package `grfext` for manipulating the sort order).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{suffix=}
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics{test}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and this has definitely taught me a few things. However, it doesn't work when the .eps file is outside the source path and I use `epstopdf` with `[outdir=./]`. I have added a new MWE for this case. Is there a solution here?